Text-based blackjack in python
This is code for a text-based game of Blackjack.
I would also like advice on how can I implement a betting system in this program. For example starting with an amount of chips and choosing how much of them to bet.
import random

card_suit = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
card_value = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
deck = [(value, suit) for suit in card_suit for value in card_value]

def card_points(card):
    if card[0] in ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']:
        return 10
    elif card[0] == 'Ace':
        return 11
    else:
        return int(card[0])
    
random.shuffle(deck)
player_cards = [deck.pop(), deck.pop()]
dealer_cards = [deck.pop()]
player_points = sum(card_points(card) for card in player_cards)
dealer_points = sum(card_points(card) for card in dealer_cards)

def points(dealer_points, player_points, dealer_cards, player_cards):
    while dealer_points < 17:
        new_card = deck.pop()
        dealer_cards.append(new_card)
        dealer_points += card_points(new_card)

    print("Dealer's Cards:", dealer_cards)
    print("Dealer's Points:", dealer_points)
    print("\n")

while True:
    print("Dealer's Cards:", dealer_cards)
    print("Dealer's Points:", dealer_points)
    print("\n")
    print("Player's Cards:", player_cards)
    print("Player's Points:", player_points)
    print("\n")
    decision = input('What will you do? ["hit" for a new card, "stand" to end the game]: ').lower()
    if decision == "hit":
        new_card = deck.pop()
        player_cards.append(new_card)
        player_points = sum(card_points(card) for card in player_cards)
        if player_points > 21:
            print("Dealer's Cards:", dealer_cards)
            print("Dealer's Points:", dealer_points)
            print("Player's Cards:", player_cards)
            print("Player's Points:", player_points)
            print("Dealer wins (player has more than 21 points)")
            break
    elif decision == "stand":
        while dealer_points < 17:
            new_card = deck.pop()
            dealer_cards.append(new_card)
            dealer_points += card_points(new_card)
        print("Dealer's Cards:", dealer_cards)
        print("Dealer's Points:", dealer_points)
        print("Player's Cards:", player_cards)
        print("Player's Points:", player_points)
        if player_points > 21:
            print("Dealer wins (player has more than 21 points).")
        elif dealer_points > 21:
            print("You win! (dealer has more than 21 points)")
        elif player_points > dealer_points:
            print("You win! (you have more points than the dealer)")
        elif player_points < dealer_points:
            print("Dealer wins (dealer has more points than the player).")
        else:
            print("It's a tie.")
        break
    else:
        print("Unknown input.")
        continue



cryptic index
deck = [(value, suit) for ... ]

def card_points(card):
    if card[0] in ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']:
        return 10
    elif card[0] == 'Ace':

The tuples in that first line are very nice and pythonic.
But this would have been even nicer:
from collections import namedtuple

Card = namedtuple('Card', 'value suit')

deck = [Card(value, suit) for ... ]

Then later on we could speak of card.value
without a cryptic [0] subscript.
enum
Consider defining class Value(Enum):,
and moving the card_points() logic into that class.
It is reasonable that a Jack object could display one way
as a string yet also return 10 as a value.
unicode cards
The way you display cards is perfectly fine.
It is worth noting that 52 unicode codepoints
offer an alternate means of displaying them.
common logic
player_cards = [deck.pop(), deck.pop()]
dealer_cards = [deck.pop()]
player_points = sum(card_points(card) for card in player_cards)
dealer_points = sum(card_points(card) for card in dealer_cards)

Consider defining class Hand:, and maintaining a list of Hands.
Then indexing it gives you either the player or the dealer,
and its .points() method gives you its total value.
DRY
Several times you print four items: {player,dealer} {cards,points}.
Please extract a helper function.
cite your reference
The code should mention up top what game it implements.
From the link in the Review Context I initially thought you meant
standard blackjack,
but this code implements a variant.
I don't see any logic for Ace sometimes being worth 11 and sometimes 1.

Overview
You've done a good job:

You leveraged code written by others with the import
Used meaningful names for many of the variables

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.
Layout
I recommend moving the functions to the top, after the import.
Having them in the middle of the code interrupts the natural flow of the
code (from a human readability standpoint).
Unused code
I was about to recommend changing the name of the points function because
it seemed too generic.  However, I realized that it is not used, so it
can be deleted.
Documentation
The card_points function always returns 11 for the Ace.  The normal rules of
Blackjack allow for the Ace to have a value of 1 in some circumstances.
You should add documentation to describe whether or not the Ace can
have a value of 1.
Input
It is great that you cast the user input into lower-case.  It would also be helpful
to allow the user to be lazy and just input h for "hit" or s for "stand".
DRY
These lines appear 3 times in the code:
        print("Dealer's Cards:", dealer_cards)
        print("Dealer's Points:", dealer_points)
        print("Player's Cards:", player_cards)
        print("Player's Points:", player_points)

You could add them into a new function, named something like show_cards,
then call the function 3 times.
